# Pymongo connection timeout from remote machine

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-ec2, pymongo, bitnami

I have a Bitnami MEAN Stack running on AWS EC2. I'm trying to connect from a remote machine using PyMongo.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
conn = MongoClient('mongodb://username:password@ec2blah.us-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27017/dbname')
```

but I keep getting an error along the lines of `pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure: timed out`

I have edited `/opt/bitnami/mongodb/mongodb.conf` to supposedly allow external connections by commenting out `bind_ip = 127.0.0.1` and uncommented `bind_ip = 0.0.0.0` and all permutations of commenting/uncommenting those lines.

I've looked over the web for about 90 minutes now trying different things but without luck!

Comment: @alecxe - I tried it, it said `MongoDB shell version: 2.6.5
url can't have host or port if you specify them individually`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the mongoDB server, do the port connection test, and make sure the DB service running well. If not, start the service.

```
telnet ec2blah.us-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com 27017
```

On the remote machine, do the port connection test, to make sure there is no firewall issue.

```
telnet ec2blah.us-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com 27017
```

If you have issue to connect, you need check `security groups` on this instance.

```
Click the ec2 instance name --> Description --> view rules, you should see the ports are opened

If not, create a new security group , such as `mongoDB`, tcp port 27017 should be opened for inbound traffic, then assign to that instance.
```

You should be fine to connect it now.

Comment: The remote machine timed out and the EC2 says `Connected to ec2blah.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.` I am in the process of creating a new security group because it only have tcp ports 22, 80, 443 set to 0.0.0.0/0   -- What ports should I open up?

Comment: TCP port 27017 should be opened for inbound traffic

Comment: I created the security group but I'm not sure its enabled. Do I have to do something else?

Comment: click the instance --> networking --> change security groups, you need manually add the new security group to that instance. That's all, you can connect it remotely.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of start-up of MongoDB, set the `bind_ip` argument to `::,0.0.0.0`

```
mongod --bind_ip ::,0.0.0.0
```

Read more in the docs of MongoDB: [IP Binding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-mongodb-configuration/).