# connect to remote mongodb using python not working from my local host

Tags: python, mongodb, ssh, remote-server

I am using python and MongoClient from pmongo to connect to **Remote mongodb**, 
note that my local machine can ssh on the remote one using public key but whenever I try to connect to the db it timeouts

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://ip/dataset?replicaSet=replica')
db = client.db_name
db['collection'].find({})
```

this will always timeout

> pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: ip:27017: timed out

- When I try to connect using **Mongo compass** it works fine, but I provide my private key for ssh tunneling
- when I use the same code inside another remote machine (not the same one with mongodb) it works fine, so I don't know why in my local machine this is the case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pymongo connection timeout from remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466198/pymongo-connection-timeout-from-remote-machine)

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous yes no luck

Answer (score 0):

```
import pymongo

url = "mongodb://ip/dataset?replicaSet=replica"
client = pymongo.MongoClient(url )
mongo = client.database
```

Comment: I believe this is the same above